# Error while indexing PDF components from Tridion CMS to Open search as binaries

Tags: sdl-tridion, elasticsearch

In Tridion CMS we have created PDF placeholder components and in those components we are adding different Pdfs which we want to publish and index in open search (AWS Cloud service).
This is done by customized SI4T extension which is added as add on service in cms.
The error which is occurring as below:
We are facing one challenge related to PDF indexing to open search. Where few of the pdf are not getting indexed.

Following is the error message in the deployer log:

```
deployercombined-service development staging WARN  ResourceTypeProcessor - Could not set attribute 'http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalStylesheet' to document builder factory
deployercombined-service development staging INFO  RemoveStateFileProcessor - ExecutionState with tcm:0-0000-00000 id was removed in 218 ms.
```

Please help me to resolve this error.The version of tridion is 9.5 and opensearch is 2.5.